90s TV series with flying hero?
IIRC there was a TV series, live action where the hero at night was flying over the city and he had some glow from his eyes and a blue superhero suit. Which was it? I'm fairly certain that he had some glowing from his eyes or from his suit and that it was american TV series running for a short while in my home (Stockholm Sweden) in 1998 or 1999. The title "Night Flyer" would suit perfectly but that is not at all the title of the production I'm looking for. 

Was it animated or live action? American? Japanese? Pakistani? Recent or old? Comedy or action? Please add some details if you can.

You might mean the US show Night Man from 1997-1999 about a superhero wore a blue suit and cape, had laser vision and flew, well, at night. Here's the intro:



[...Not to be confused with fighter of the Day Man. ;)]

Yes! That's the one!

Lieutenant Dann? Really? /s
